# Cannot run aws.push for local repository head

Tags: git, redmine, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Ruby project (redmine) on an Elastic Beanstalk server using the Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface, but when I try to launch the environment i get the following error:

$ eb start
Starting application "redmine".
Would you like to deploy the latest Git commit to your environment? [y/n]: y 
Cannot run aws.push for local repository HEAD:

And thats all that is printed out. As a reference, I was following the instructions here: http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, so I hit "n" and let the environment start without deploying any code.  After it was Green, I used `aws.push` to deploy my code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because I had no Ruby installed on my local machine.
Did you satisfy all requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else hits this error in a different context, this can also happen if you have too many application versions under one Elastic Beanstalk environment. The limit is 500.

When you run: `git aws.push` instead of `eb push` it will give you an error about having too many application versions, if that is the case.

To resolve, just login to AWS and you can delete some of your older application versions from there.